# What happened when new Object() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend

Just showing the code:

```js
const a = {
  age: 1
};
const b = new Object(a);
console.log(a === b); //true
```

It troubled me why the result is `true` instead of `false` ?

Comment: Why would you expecting false?

Comment: @Isaac - On the fact of it, `new Object` would seem to create an object.

Comment: Object is super type of all in javascript. In your case it will assign same type and value to b

Comment: Maybe you would be happier with `const b = Object.create(a)` Although, it's also not obvious what this does, because b is not a copy of a as you might think.

Comment: when we use the `new` keyword it returns an empty object `{}`.

Comment: @AravindS - Not always (as shown above).

Answer (score 2):

Because that's how the [`Object` constructor](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-constructor) is defined. If the argument you pass it is an object, it just returns that object instead of a new one. (In theory, a new object was created by `new` but then thrown away; in practice that can be optimized away — see "Note" below.)

The logic in the `Object` constructor, ignoring a minor detail, is: If no argument was given or the argument is `null` or `undefined`, create and return a new object; otherwise, return the result of converting the argument to object. Since the argument you're passing in is already an object, that conversion doesn't have to do anything.

Just for completeness: Constructors in general can make `new` return an existing object instead of a new one by returning a non-`null` object. (If the constructor doesn't return anything — the normal case — or returns a non-object value like 42, the object created by `new` is returned.) Here's an example:

```js
"use strict";

class Example1 {
  constructor(arg) {
    if (arg && typeof arg === "object") {
      return arg;
    }
  }
}
const a = {};
const e1 = new Example1(a);
console.log(a === e1); // true

class Example2 {
  constructor(arg) {
    if (arg && typeof arg === "object") {
      return arg;
    }
    return 42; // 42 isn't an object
  }
}
const e2 = new Example2();
console.log(e2); // [object Object], not 42
```

---

**Note:** In theory, using `new` always creates a new object, and then if the constructor returns a different object, the new object just gets thrown away. In practice, JavaScript engines are free to optimize the creation of that new object away if the constructor doesn't access `this`.

**Note 2:** It's perhaps worth noting that using `new` with the `Object` constructor is never necessary. `Object` is a bit of an odd constructor: As defined by the spec, it ignores the object `new` creates entirely. `new Object()` and `Object()` do the same thing, as do `new Object(value)` and `Object(value)`. Again, this is unusual.

Comment: @Kaiido - Good thought! Updated.

Comment: Is there any reason one would use `b = new Object(a)` instead of `b = a`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just a curious what happens when we use Object.create()

Comment: @MarkMeyer - Not `b = new Object(a)` literally, no. You might want `b = Object(a)` if your goal is to convert `a` from a primitive number, string, or boolean to the equivalent `Number`, `String`, or `Boolean` instance. But that's a rare thing to want to do. In fact, using `new` with `Object` is never necessary, the `Object` constructor always ignores the object `new` creates.

Comment: @UllasHunka - [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is very, very different from `new Object`. It creates a new object whose prototype what you pass in.

Comment: when I read vue-cli source code, a snip of code   as follows:  
if (req !== Object(req)) {
   throw new Error('meta.js needs to expose an object')
}

Comment: @chesszhang - Did you have a question about that? It seems to be an odd (to my eye) way to check whether `req` is an object. (I wouldn't do it that way. I'd probably do `req && typeof req === "object"`.)

Comment: @chesszhang - I wouldn't check that way, but it does work.

Comment: Yap, I also think your method is better